# How to add scrolling feature in blackberry 9300 to show long content in a small field

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

How can we show Scrolling feature in blackberry 9300 (Small screen) to show more line of contents.

Thanks
Aditya

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm=new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);
```

Add all your fields to vfm.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Property of your `Manager` as `Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR`. Than add your `Field (LabelField , ButtonField ... )`  in that `Manager` and try .